# Excel VBA-Add conditional items to multiple combo boxes

Tags: excel, vba

In column C of my worksheet in Excel 2013, I have a list of categories of items that my company sells. In each cell of column D is a combo box. Column C has items like "cookies", "cakes", "muffins" (obviously, hundreds of different items).
In columns K and L, I have a list of categories and options. Is there any way to make a conditional formula for all the combo boxes? Something like:

```
Sub ComboBoxLoad()

For i = 1 To 30
With "combobox" & i
If Range("K2") = Range("C" & i) Then
.AddItem Range("L2")
End If
End With
With "combobox" & i
If Range("K3") = Range("C" & i) Then
.AddItem Range("L3")
End If
End With
With "combobox" & i
If Range("K4") = Range("C" & i) Then
.AddItem Range("L4")
End If
End With
With "combobox" & i
If Range("K5") = Range("C" & i) Then
.AddItem Range("L5")
End If
End With
With "combobox" & i
If Range("K6") = Range("C" & i) Then
.AddItem Range("L6")
End If
End With
Next

End Sub
```

Thank you so much!